# Crash because of Google Mobile Ads: Collection was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: ios, admob

I got a crash into my app because of Google Mobile Ads SDK.

I am using their SDK into my app to show ads, however the view controller (`MoreController`) being presented when crashing doesn't load any ad request... so I have no idea of what's going on. Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It happens while fetching banner views (from different views). The array that is being enumerated contains `GADOMIDAdSession` objects. Did you find any solution for this?